# Getting the messages back to the same command line from where the MFC application was launched

Tags: c++, mfc

I am executing an **MFC Application** from command line which takes four command line arguments.One of the argument is the directory path.
If the path is wrong then I want to show a Message "Bad Path" on the same **command line**

**Note : For showing I don't want to take a new command line .**

Comment: To inherit the parent console you have to make your application a console application; on the downside, a console is shown even if your application is started not from the command line.

Comment: As an alternative use the return codes. Define a return code of say 99 that will mean "Bad Path" and exit your MFC Application with this return code. Your command line will then show that return code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically that's not supported. There is sort of known "workaround" for that, using AttachConsole(-1) to attach parent process console. Has disadvantages of course (like, parent console will not wait for your EXE to terminate, because it's not a "console" app). Anyways, basic idea:

```
void WriteToParentConsole()
{
    if (AttachConsole(-1))
    {
        char msg[] = "Bad Path!";
        WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), msg, sizeof(msg), NULL, NULL);

        // send ENTER (optional)
        // ::SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_CHAR, VK_RETURN, 0);

        FreeConsole();
    }
}
```

You can check out this article for example, or just google something on AttachConsole/GUI vs Console for more information:
http://www.tillett.info/2013/05/13/how-to-create-a-windows-program-that-works-as-both-as-a-gui-and-console-application/

Comment: Thanks a million Nikolay. it worked exactly as I wanted it to.